# Surface plot using multiple excel files

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, 3d

I'm just a beginner with MATLAB.

I need to represent my data using a 3D plot. I tried using the surf function but in my case this is a little bit tricky. From the code you will see that I am looping through multiple excel files to extract data from it.
Using a 3-dimensional plot I need to represent my Fv array as the 'X' coordinate, my FTsiga as the 'Y' coordinate and the the third coordinate should be each excel file that I am looping through.
A plot of (Fv,FTsiga) looks like the figure that is attached herewith.
[Fv(x-axis) , FTsiga(y-axis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eET3X.jpg)

The code that I have written so far couldn't seem to execute because MATLAB crashed due to insufficient memory or because it got stuck in a loop. The latter is more likely I guess.

```
    % Matlab trial code: Trying to loop through excel files strored in directory

source_dir = 'C:\UTwente\Q4\Structural Health and Condition monitoring\Case Roadbridge (Zwartewaterbrug)\Excel data'
source_files = dir(fullfile(source_dir, '*xlsx'));
len = length(source_files);
matrix = zeros(len,32);

X = zeros(len,32); Y = zeros(len,32); Z = zeros(len,32);
%looping through excel file in directory
for i=1:len
    data= xlsread(source_files(i).name,'Measurement data');
    for j=1:32
        sig = data(:,j);
        sig = sig - mean(sig);                                      % Remove d-c Offset
        L = length(sig);
        Fs = 1000;                                                  % Sampling Frequency
        Fn = Fs/2;                                                  % Nyquist Frequency
        FTsig = fft(sig)/L;
        Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(length(FTsig)/2)+1)*Fn;             % Frequency Vector
        Iv = 1:length(Fv);                                          % Index Vector
        FTsiga = double(abs(FTsig(Iv))*2);                          % Truncate, Magnitude, Convert To Double
        sgf_sm = sgolayfilt(FTsiga, 5, 501);                        % Create ‘sgolayfilt’ Filtered FFT
        [~, idx] = max( sgf_sm );                                   % Getting the value of the modal frequency
        peakfreq = Fv( idx );
        matrix(i,j) = peakfreq;                                     % Matrix of all peak frequencies
        [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(Fv,FTsiga,i);
    end
    surf(Fv,FTsiga,i);
end
```

Comment: How much memory do you have and how much does your code require? What error message are you receiving? Does your code work correctly  if you reduce the measurement data in each excel file and try with  less number of files? You haven't provided enough information to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To explain it simply. I need to plot multiple 2D plots to form a 3D plot. I think there is an error in the logic of my code but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: So at the moment you don't know if their is logical error or problem due to less memory. So start debugging. Remove the loop and run it for a single sample file with less number of measurements for which you can verify the results.  Use breakpoints or just run it line by line and check if you're getting the expected output at each line or not.  When you're done with a single file then go for the loops